# begin on next commit message but do not commit in git

Tags: git, commit

I know that `git commit -m [msg]` lets me enter a commit message and at the same time commits the added files.

I am looking for a git command that lets me append to the **next** git commit message, but not commiting.
Ie. the next time I enter `git commit -m [msg]`, What I just wrote would be prepended to that message.

Comment: What do you mean by "next" commit message?  If a commit hasn't happened yet, then how can you append something to it?

Comment: I mean the next time you enter `git commit` in that branch.

Comment: I don't see the need/point of doing this.  It is not surprising that Git does not have such a feature, because in general it is not possible to know what your next commit may or may not be.

Comment: Ok, I probably misunderstood something then. But looking at something like torvalds/linux repo, there can be multiple parts of a commit message.

Comment: For example, say I wanted to test a module with 5 functions, and publish the added tests as a single commit. Say I only had time to write tests for 2 of those functions before dinner. It would then be advantageous to be able to 'save the state' of what I was doing in the future commit, so I could remember that I only had 3 functions left to test, when I came back after dinner.

Comment: AFAIK the closest you can get to this is `commit --amend`, which is not exactly what you are asking for, but lets you build up a commit by modifying it after the fact instead. It should get you to the same place at the end. Just don't amend an already-pushed commit.

Answer (score 3):

You can't start (or add) to a git message for a commit that has not happened yet.  I sounds like this may be a small part of a bigger commit.  For these types if scenarios it is best practice to create a new branch and have several small commits with individual commit messages as opposed to a large commit.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, It of course makes sense to commit small and often rather than large and seldom. I explained my thinking behind this question in the comments of my original post!

Comment: This type of information should be kept separate from the repository.  Repositories are for storing code.  You are attempting to use it to track work.  This should be done in a system that is meant for tracking work like a ticketing system i.e. JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
git commit --amend "message to enter"
```

It will add message in the previous commit